# Split list by class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, class, split

I have an unordered list, and some of its items have classes like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="specialOne">Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li class="specialTwo">Some Content</li>
    <li class="specialThree">Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to split it into two different unordered lists, one of them with the list items without a class, and the other gathering the list items with classes, like so:

```
   <ul>
       <li>Some Content</li>
       <li>Some Content</li>
       <li>Some Content</li>
       <li>Some Content</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
       <li class="specialOne">Some Content</li>
       <li class="specialTwo">Some Content</li>
       <li class="specialThree">Some Content</li>
   </ul>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079608/jquery-group-list-items-by-class) but it groups the lists by similar class, and I want all the classes merged together.

Is there any simple code to get this? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you requested, matching any `li` that have the `class` `attr`

---

## Demo

```js
// Create new list and append to end of body
$("body").append("<ul class='class-list'></ul>");

// Append all list items that have the class attribute
$("ul.class-list").append( $("li[class]") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<ul>
    <li class="specialOne">Some Content + class</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
    <li class="specialTwo">Some Content + class</li>
    <li class="specialThree">Some Content + class</li>
    <li>Some Content</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, and if the goal changes, and you want to target only *some* specific classes, you can do like so:// Create new list and append to end of body
$("body").append("<ul class='class-list'></ul>");

// Append all list items that have the class attribute
$("ul.class-list").append( $("li.Catego1,li.Catego2,li.Catego3,li.EtcEtc") );